# dynamically change html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have some checkboxes, once I check one of these the ID of the checkbox is sent to a function. I want this function to change the checkbox to a `<img>`element with the same ID.

I have tried

```
document.getElementById(ID).innerHTML = '<img src="image.png" id="' + ID + '"/>';
```

But this doesn't work, is it possible to change a element or would I need to create a new one using the same ID?

Thanks

Comment: Please bear in mind that if you remove one element from, and create another element in, the document *with the same `id`* you may find you quickly develop CSS problems.

Comment: In this case I don't have any CSS related to the id's i'm using.

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't allowed to use jQuery in your project?

Comment: Its for a uni project, everything has to be pure javascript no libarys etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise that rather than replace one element with another you make one visible and one invisible eg...

```
document.getElementById(ID).style.display='none';
```

and

```
document.getElementById(ID).style.display='block';
```

And I would think of a way round the same ID constraint. Why do you need them to have exactly the same ID?

Comment: Thanks, I would usually do this but the first element would no longer be required so I thought it would be better to remove it all together?

Comment: You could remove it, and make the `img` visible. Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: How would I remove it? jQuery isn't allowed in my project :(

Comment: You need to call `removeChild()` on the parent node of the element you wish to remove. eg `parentNode.removeChild(nodeToRemove)`. http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/met_element_removechild.asp

Answer (score 2):

in pure javascript you can do something like:

```
function changeToImage(el) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo29.png');
    img.setAttribute('ID', el.getAttribute('id'));
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    parent.appendChild(img);
    parent.removeChild(el);
}
```

then from your html you would do

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="changeToImage(this)" />
```

note that this may not be cross-browser proof.... you can also use jquery to simplify things

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a new element and remove the old one.  In case you need it, here's a quick article on adding and removing elements using javascript: http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/

By way of explaining why you can't do what you were trying to do, your elements are represented in the DOM as different "types" (strictly speaking, this is not true, but it's a useful representation), and you can't just change the "type" of an object by changing its underlying markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write like this one.
It worked for me.
Replace the innerHTML with HTML

```
document.getElementById(ID).HTML = '<img src="image.png" id="' + ID + '"/>';
```