# Dynamic HTML in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, dynamic, thymeleaf

I am creating a Spring MVC + Thymeleaf project. I would like the user to have control over some parts of the page, meaning that user could change text and format is as well with colors, font sizes, etc., using HTML tags. However, I have not found any way how to insert dynamic HTML into thymleaf HTML template. Is there any way how to do it ?

EDIT: Do I really have to use JS in order to be able to achieve that ? Thymeleaf really does not have any way of inserting dynamically generated HTML inside static HTML th template ?

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly should the user be able to do that? Are you speaking of a wysiwyg editor? Should the user type in source code in a textfield?

Comment: Yes, something like TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor for some text parts of the page. Fo example user should be able to add formated article to the page. So tags like font, br, table, b, i, etc. should be all supported.

Comment: I'd recommend doing some research - for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761284/thymeleaf-spring-dynamic-replace), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372318/dynamically-change-html-element), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990089/dynamically-change-css-rules-in-javascript-or-jquery) (there are plenty more variations you can probably find, too). Try building something - this site is more about helping to find specific solutions to specific problems.

Comment: Non of these solves my issue actually. I know about fragments but then again they are static in terms of HTML. The only solution is probably via JS which is sad because I was hoping for thymeleaf solution but I guess th is more limited than I thought.

Comment: There is [unescaped text](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#unescaped-text) - but that comes with **security risks** - especially if the text is being provided directly by the user. I mention it only to recommend you **don't do that**.

Comment: One additional thought: Thymeleaf templates and fragments don't have to be predefined in files on the classpath. They can be built on-the-fly - as long as you know what they are called, so you can refer to them; and how to find them using the appropriate [resolver](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#the-template-resolver). There are various [types of resolver](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#template-resolvers) you can use, depending on your different needs. A template can even be a Java `String`. (But always watch out for security risks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thymeleaf doesn't limit you in using any frontend libraries you like, you can just use any existing WYSIWYG editor you like. TinyMCE is one of them. Another great editor is Summernote. Here's a Tutorial describing in detail how to use it with Spring and Thymeleaf: https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/spring-boot-bootstrap-thymeleaf-rich-text-editor

But again: there's nothing special about Thymeleaf. You can use any HTML/JavaScript WYSIWYG editor you like.

Comment: I know I can use any editor. But how do I insert HTML formated text into thymeleaf template ? <div th:value="<p>text</p>"></div> does not work.

Comment: Ah OK. This can be done using `th:utext` which inserts the content without escaping html. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433224/inject-html-into-thymeleaf-template. But as @andrewjames describes: this can cause serious security issues

Comment: Thanks. th:utext was exactly what I was looking for!